# Android: Disable highlighting in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, click, highlighting

How can I turn off the orange highlight when clicking an item in a GridView?

I haven't been able to find a solution in the documentation or through testing.

Comment: Related: "[Disable Android GridView highlighting completely (disable selection)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3159897)" if you want to disable not just highlighting but selection and use the GridView just for layout, or handle selection manually via onTouch/Click/etc listeners.

Answer (score 146):

Use `android:listSelector="#00000000"` in your `GridView` element in your XML layout file.

Comment: On listviews android:listSelector="@null" does the trick but on gridview that wont work. But setting it transparent does work =/

Comment: Note that elements of the selected view may still change in response to selection (e.g., TextViews changing to their "selected" color state).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3187007/85950) for how to disable selection entirely.

Comment: You can use android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" if you are afraid of numbers

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare , can you pls help.. I have a grid view with image as a single item in grid When I m clicking in space left around image ,I get touch feedback from gridview but no feedback on clicking on the image.. what can I do? thanks.

Answer (score 37):

Another option is to reference the transparent color via @android:color/transparent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 19):

I did the same thing in code using

```
GridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 11):

Add this property to gridview

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Done! this is a solution.
thank you :)

Comment: to hide highlighted from gridview.

Answer (score 5):

Try It...

android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

Just set below property in your XML file.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:listSelector="#00000000"` or `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` in your GridView XML element like bellow.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```