# Disable Android GridView highlighting completely (disable selection)

Tags: android, gridview, selector

I'm trying to disable the highlighting of objects in a GridView in Android 2.2.

I found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865683/android-disable-highlighting-in-gridview) saying that I should set the selector to a transparent ColorDrawable (`android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`), but the views in my GridView are still dimmed when I select them.

I'm just using the GridView to display static objects in a grid. None of these objects will be selected. Would it be better to just use a basic view and draw my images manually?

Comment: check this out

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415844/disable-gridview-item-onclick-and-enable-only-on-child-view

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the definition of your Adapter for the GridView, you will have to override the following methods:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    return false;
}
```

This will cause all of the items in your grid to be non-selectable, and will get rid of the highlight completely.

Comment: If you need childs to be focusable try android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"

Comment: thanks a lot here, if you have custom objects in your list (views..) and overwrite their onclicklistener, you can select them :=) 
perfect :)

Comment: this disable item selection altogether

Answer (score 39):

For keeping the items clickable you should use below attr. in your GridView xml:

> android:listSelector="#00000000"

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866074/928591

Comment: @Radu This solution was explicitly mentioned in the question as not working.

Comment: better use android:listSelector="@null"

Answer (score 1):

Just `Set v.setOnClickListener(null);`

Comment: This is in your Adapter.getView method

Comment: I still needed to be able to get click events for the GridView, but I'm sure that would work in other situations.

Comment: this will create an exception

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the visual aspect of the selection, you can do the following:

```
gridview.getSelector().setAlpha(0);
```