# disable gridview item onClick and enable only on child view

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I have a gridview with imageview and textview in each gridview item. I want to disable onclick of grid view item and enable it only for imageview. Is there any way this can be achieved. I have have lot of space between each grid view item and if i have onclick enabled for each gridview item then ontimeclick listener will be called even if i click on empty spaces to avoid this i am planing to have onclick only for imageview.... pls suggest how this can be done...

Comment: How you set images in gridview ? If its an arraylist / array then you can check if images[position] null or not.

Comment: you can set onClick of image in adapte directly. but do not set itemclickListener for gridview.

Comment: @Hardy I have created relative layout with textview and imageview and used this layout as gridview item..

Comment: @Biraj... i have removed set itemclicklistener added setClickable for image view with true... still the grid view item is clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `android:clickable="false"` for gridview in your xml.

And, you can write onClick for imageview inside custom adapter where you have populated your gridview.

Also try,

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for your gridview in xml.

Comment: yes. i have tried this... but still the entire gridview item is clickable... i want to disble on the gridview item and enable only for  imageview inside it... thanks

Comment: Ya, then it is that, already your gridview was not clickable. Only your row item in gridview was receiving the click. Anyway, glad it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(count==1)
    {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              switch (position) {
                  case 0:
                      count++;
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, ssss.class);
                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  intent.putExtras(bundle);
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  context.startActivity(intent);
                break;
                  case 1:
                     button.setEnabled(true);
                      break;

                  case 2:
                      button.setEnabled(true);
                      break;


              }
          }
      });
```

Use This in Level Adapter