# Android PNG transparent image on background

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout, transparent

I have a problem with changing button background image.
So i have 2 images (png-24 transparent background). 
Images are a simple circle and the same circle but with some outerglow ). 
I have the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ticketing_row_topup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/pressed_topup_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topup_name"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="22dip"
    android:text="€"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topup_display_amount"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    android:textColor="#0d457f"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the pressed_topup_button.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:state_enabled="false">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_topup_glow" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_topup" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_topup" /> 
</selector>
```

The LinearLayout is used to populate a GridView in each cell.
When i click the cell the behavior is correct (the glow is displayed) but also a yellow color is display on the corner of the image (where suppose to be transparent). How can i fix  that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add a screenshot also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
 android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

to your GridView declaration.

See this:
[Android: Disable highlighting in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865683/android-disable-highlighting-in-gridview)