# Gridview item showing shadow on click

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview

I am using gridview for my application dashborad, but when i `click` on item, it shows the shadow. How can i remove showdow on `click`.

Here is my item grid `xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_icon_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/launcher_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `gridview` layout.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    tools:context="com.tech.reader.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <GridView

     android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="80dp" 
     android:numColumns="3" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here i am attaching link picture of my dashboard in click mode in which i tried to explain my problem.
[dashboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yla5vpi5ew9ozwn/dashboard.png?dl=0)

Comment: Try setting the list_selector attribute on your GridView to a transparent color: android:listSelector="#00000000"

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:listSelector="#00000000"` in your `GridView` element in your XML layout file.

Reference [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866074/5184722)